# textview giving null pointer

Tags: java, android

I hate errors like this. I'm getting a null pointer. I know what it means. I just don't understand how i'm getting it since i know that the item it should be pointing to does exist. I'm creating a textview that will be updated by the opengl renderer. The textview provides a score. I've created the textview in XML and given it a 'id', then i reference it in my program and update it through the renderer. Icreate TextView variables globally then I initialize them in the onCreate() method. Then I created a method to set the text. Which is called inside of my renderer class.

Here is my java code

```
View r1;
TextView score3, score4;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //set app to full screen and keep screen on
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(Main.layout);//R.layout.gl_triallayout;

        r1 = findViewById(Main.id);////R.id.gl_triallayout;
        score3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.threeScore);
        score4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fourScore);
        ......
        }

 public int get3(int i){
        score3.setText("Score" + String.valueOf(i));
        ((RelativeLayout) r1).bringChildToFront(findViewById(R.id.threeScore));
        Log.i("i", String.valueOf(i));
        return i;
    }
```

XML code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/threeScore"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Score"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textColor="#ffff00"/>
```

Update

Main class

```
   public void Trial(View v) {
        layout = R.layout.gl_triallayout;
        id = R.id.glTrialLayout;
        gameType = 0;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, OpenGLActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void PlayGame(View v) {
        layout = R.layout.gl_layout;
        id = R.id.glLayout;
        gameType = 1;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, OpenGLActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I hate the idea of clutter stackoverflow with the same question so if the answer is immensely simple could you give it to me in the comments. then i could delete this.

Comment: Can you post your logcat error plz ?

Comment: you didnt set your contentview. use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: set your layout file in onCreate() setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: What is `Main.layout`? Normally you would use the R class.

Comment: Change your setContentView(Main.layout) to setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: Guys please see update. Main.layout is a variable in my Main class that has R.layout.gl_triallayout

Comment: @Maxouille my logcat says error with line score3.setText("Score" + String.valueOf(i));

Comment: setContentView(Main.layout); this is wrong.Resource names must start with a lowercase letter.for example: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: @krishnan its not a resource its a static variable from my Main class

Comment: you are setting your layout. Thats fine. But null pointer exception is happening because it is not able to access your text view in the inflated layout. once try inflating the layout directly instead of inflating it from main class. As you are using layout ids directly clean the project every time before running.

Comment: Textview score3 points to R.id.threeScore in your xml layout and your layout value also changes based on certain condition.,it may be either gl_triallayout or gl_layout, so Textview  score3 should be present in both of your layout xml files to avoid nullpointer condition .i.e score3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.threeScore); in activity should either point to any of layout xml textview id, so both layout should have TextView with android:id="@+id/threeScore".

Answer (score 2):

Your

```
setContentView(Main.layout)
```

should be

```
setContentView(R.layout.filename)
```

In the above code, you should change your layout file name based on your need like `R.layout.activity_main`.

Same applies to,

```
 r1 = findViewById(Main.id);////R.id.gl_triallayout;
```

What is `r1`?

If it's a button, it should be

```
 r1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gl_triallayout);////R.id.gl_triallayout;
```

If it's a Editext,

```
 r1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gl_triallayout);////R.id.gl_triallayout
```

If it's a TextView,

```
 r1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gl_triallayout);////R.id.gl_triallayout
```

Also, In your `XML` layout, where's the view for `score4` and `r1`?

I think you should start learning the basics of `Android` first.

Comment: There's no proper code to given a solution. You're having a method, but there's no declaration where you are accessing the method and so on.